# fail to start activity from service

Tags: android, firebase, android-activity, android-service

Before asking this question. I was looking first that anybody else also got this issue or not. But I didn't found any.
Brief:
I want to start a activity when a message comes via FCM.
in the onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) whenever message incoming am handling with this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IncomingMeetingConference.class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
```

it work fine if app foreground. But when I make app in background. Activity is not launching.

so far I observed that in console am getting

```
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:771108234
```

but no message for ActivityThread related.

whereas when app is in foreground I get ActivityThread log message in console. Please let me know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Use a PendingIntent and put a notification for the user

Comment: Also see something about how incoming calls display messages to the user in background.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos thank you. I was not getting how to know if app in background or foreground. after some search I got my answer and shared as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do that. This behaviour is discouraged. You are not allowed to interrupt the user when you get a message from the server. The correct behaviour is to show a `Notification`. The user can then tap on the `Notification` to view the `Activity`. This allows the user to decide when and if he wants to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks David for giving me right idea to do it. so i found how a code to check app is in background or foreground by

```
public boolean foregrounded() {
    ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo appProcessInfo = new ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo();
    ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState(appProcessInfo);
    return (appProcessInfo.importance == IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND || appProcessInfo.importance == IMPORTANCE_VISIBLE)
}
```

if app is in foreground it will return true. If app in background it will return false.